# SourceMap path to file and plugins in webpackConfig

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

This code generating maps file with path: http://my-site.dev/resources/less/style.less

```
mix.webpackConfig({ 
output: { devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]' }, 
})
.sourceMaps(false, 'inline-source-map');
```

I need path:
file:///D:/my-site/resources/less/style.less
this don't helped me:

```
devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: 'file:///D:/[namespace]'
```

I tried this plugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/

```
const SourceMapDevToolPlugin = require('source-map-dev-tool-plugin');
mix
  .webpackConfig({ 
    devtool: false,
    plugins: [
      
      new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: "[file].map",
        moduleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]',
      }),
    ]
```

output:
*Error: ReferenceError: SourceMapDevToolPlugin is not defined*

I don't know how can install webpack plugins.
I have same trouble with const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin'):
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/npm-install-webpack-plugin/issues/122

Comment: i need same. Removes the webpack:/// prefix:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/622#issuecomment-476130736

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
.webpackConfig({ output: {
  devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info => {
    let path = 'D:/my-site/resources/less/';
    return `file:///${path}${info.resourcePath.slice(2)}`;
  }
}
}).sourceMaps(false, 'inline-source-map');
```

Sadly, styles not saving in the tab "Styles", but it work in the Sources
[image: styles]